# EF Core and MySQL - "CREATE DATABASE" Sql command gives error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I ran into a problem when trying to create a database scheme in MySQL using EF Core.

Error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax ; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near MY_SHCEME_NAME"

EF Core version: 2.2.6

MySQL Server version: 5.7.19

Code:

```
 using (var dbEntities = new MyDbContext())
 using (var transaction = dbEntities.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
 {
    try
    {
        dbEntities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"CREATE DATABASE {databaseConnection.Schema}");
        // other commands...                  
        dbEntities.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         transaction.Rollback();
         log.Error("ConfigureDatabase transaction failed!", ex);
         throw;
     }
 }
```

This piece of code was working with same MySQL server while using ASP.NET (.NET Framework).
I tried both Pomelo and MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore connectors, as well when trying similar operation using ADO.NET API.

Later I ran into this Pomelo [issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/643) where they seem to be resolving same issue, so in "MyDbContext" I added:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
        ConnectionStringManager.Instance.ConnectionString, 
        mySqlOptionsAction => mySqlOptionsAction.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 19), ServerType.MySql));
}
```

This also did not help. Other EF core features seems to work fine and read/write to database.